# Pidgin theme problem

Tags: pidgin

I installed pidgin on my windows 7 64 bit.

I want to have a theme, and found a lot of theme libary e.g.: http://art.gnome.org/themes/gtk2/

Every single site in the world tells me something about a theme changer and a "Common Files/GTK+/Theme" Folder.

But in my whole windows installation is no GTK+ Folder and I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Pidgin FAQ addresses this issue](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Using%20Pidgin#win32_gtk_theme). First, you need to obtain a GTK Theme switcher. The recommended downloading GTK+ Themes and GTK+ Theme Switcher, which can be obtained through [this Sourceforge project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gtk-win/). Then, copy the `lib` and `share` directories from GTK+ Themes into `<Pidgin Installation Directory>\Gtk` directory, merging with the existing directories. Then, copy `gtk2_prefs.exe` from the GTK Theme Switcher zip file into your `<Pidgin Installation Directory>\Gtk\bin` directory. Run `gtk2_prefs.exe` to choose a new theme - be sure to "Apply to all users".

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [GTK-Win](http://gtk-win.sourceforge.net/) and especially [GTK-PreferenceTool](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/gtk-win/gtk2_prefs-0.4.1.bin-win32.zip?download) ?

[image]